# Synchronization of onclick function from different devices

Tags: javascript, php, html

The code I have is at http://www.lesha.wemakesites.ru/

What it does is givng out reversed string and counting times the servise was used.
What I wanna do is that once the page is opened and somebody runs the code on any other device I can see the total number changed **without reloading the page**.
To do so I'm using 2 ajax-requests of following view:

```
var ajax_result = $.ajax({
        url: 'count.php',
        method: 'post',
        success: function () {}
    })

    var ajax_write = $.ajax({
        url: 'count.txt',
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("total_global").style.display = ("none");
            document.getElementById("global").style.display = ("inline");
            document.getElementById("global").style.color = ("red");
            document.getElementById("global").innerHTML = data;

        }
```

In count.php I have:

```
<?php 
    $file = 'count.txt'; 
    $file_open = file_get_contents($file);
    $file_open = (int)$file_open;
    $file_open = $file_open + 1;
    file_put_contents($file, $file_open);
    echo($file_open);
    ?>
```

and after I dynamically show the result with js.
Nevertheless I don't see changes when I run it from my phone until I reload the page at my PC.

Comment: Try adding `cache: false` option to prevent the browser from caching the file.

Comment: @Barmar the situation didn't change at all. Cashing is also disabled in the browser where I run tests

Comment: Every time I click "Reverse it" the counts go up. Isn't that what's supposed to happen?

Comment: @Barmar  it is. What I wanna do is to see it changed on my PC when I reverse string from my phone e.g. without reloading the page at PC